# Only upload image if an image is selected

Tags: android, if-statement, select, upload, imageview

I use following Code to select an image from gallery and display it with an ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
    super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
    if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
        Uri uri = I.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Currently, with the method `ImageUploadToServerFunction()` the upload will be started, also if no image is selected. Finally the app crashes.

My question:
What can I do, not to start the upload and post a `Toast` if there is no image selected?

```
if (imageView == ???) {
    ImageUploadToServerFunction();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No image selected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Updated answer: With doing this if-statement when clicking on the Button (android:onClick="OnButton"), the app crahes the same way than before if no image is selected. Why? What's wrong?

```html
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
  
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anghinzu);
        
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivFoto);
        SelectImageGallery = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);

        SelectImageGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image From Gallery"), 1);
            }
        });
    }
        
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RC, int RQC, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RC, RQC, I);
        if (RC == 1 && RQC == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = I.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void ImageUploadToServerFunction(){
      ...
    }
    
    public void OnButton(View view) {
        //Upload Image
        if (hasImage(imageView)) {
            ImageUploadToServerFunction();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Kein Bild ausgewählt!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check if uri is not null then upload it otherwise not !!!!

Comment: RESULT can't be OK if the user pressed back (only way to exit the gallery without selecting an image). So as long as you check the result value it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can check if that `ImageView` has any image or not like this,

```
private boolean hasImage(@NonNull ImageView view) {
    Drawable drawable = view.getDrawable();
    boolean hasImage = (drawable != null);

    if (hasImage && (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
       hasImage = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() != null;
    }

    return hasImage;
}
```

Comment: How can I do this if-statement? See edited post above.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Why? For detailed code, see edited question above.

Comment: Is there nobody who can help me?

Comment: Give me some time I will do that and will post the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(imageView.getDrawable() == null){
    // Image not exist...
} else {
    // Image Exists!
}
```

This code is working fine, I just found it from StackOverflow.